# Get position of character at specific index

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to find out the position of a character in a div.

e.g.

```
<div>This is a very long multi-line text that overflows and wraps<div>
```

I would like to find the absolute x and y-position of the character at position 24 (i.e. '-'). Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get the text offset position in plain JavaScript without wrapping text with an element:

```js
var characters = document.querySelector('.characters');
var charactersText = characters.textContent;
var charAtIndex = 25;
var offsetPosition;

characters.textContent = '';
for (var i = 0; i < charactersText.length; i++) {
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(charactersText[i]);
    characters.appendChild(textNode);
    if (i === charAtIndex) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(textNode);
        var rects = range.getClientRects();
        offsetPosition = {
            left: rects[0].left,
            top: rects[0].top
        };
    }
}

alert(JSON.stringify(offsetPosition, null, 2));
```

```html
<div class="characters">This is a very long multi-line text that overflows and wraps</div>
```